# How to filter by field a top_hits aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am facing some problems to create my query on a very big index of 600M documents. I'm close to resolve it however I got stuck.

The type of documents I have is the following:

```
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Doe",
    "company_domain" : "google",
    "provider_a_id" : "1234",
    "provider_b_id" : "14"
}
```

I need to return 2 contacts per company, where the `provider_a_id` matches from a list of IDs I previously obtained.

I have come with this aggregation that it returns 2 contacts per company:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "COMPANIES": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company_domain.keyword",
        "order": { "_key": "asc" }, 
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "EMPLOYEES": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is pretty good since I could solve one part, however the problem is that I need now to narrow the search using the `provider_a_id` as well. Would need to do something like:

```
        "EMPLOYEES": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2
            // provider_a_id is in [.......] // list with 10K Ids
          }
        }
```

Do you know how I can tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use filter aggregation before top_hits.
I have filtered on a single value(term) you can uses terms aggregation to filter on a list

Mapping

```
PUT testindex7/_mappings
{
  "properties": {
    "first_name" :{
      "type": "text"
    },
    "last_name" : {
      "type": "text"
    },
    "company_domain" :{
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
         "keyword":{
           "type": "keyword"
         }  
      }
    },
    "provider_a_id" : {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "provider_b_id" : {
      "type": "integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
 [
      {
        "_index" : "testindex7",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "OvU4OG0BCNyxVsPT3Xtn",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "a",
          "last_name" : "b",
          "company_domain" : "google",
          "provider_a_id" : "100",
          "provider_b_id" : "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex7",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "O_U5OG0BCNyxVsPTAHsD",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "c",
          "last_name" : "d",
          "company_domain" : "google",
          "provider_a_id" : "101",
          "provider_b_id" : "2"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "testindex7",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "PPU5OG0BCNyxVsPTJ3tZ",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "first_name" : "e",
          "last_name" : "f",
          "company_domain" : "google",
          "provider_a_id" : "102",
          "provider_b_id" : "3"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Query:

```
GET testindex7/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "COMPANIES": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company_domain.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        },
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "EMPLOYEES": {
          "filter": { 
            "terms": {
              "provider_a_id": [100,101]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_emps": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 2
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "COMPANIES" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "google",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "EMPLOYEES" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "top_emps" : {
              "hits" : {
                "total" : {
                  "value" : 2,
                  "relation" : "eq"
                },
                "max_score" : 1.0,
                "hits" : [
                  {
                    "_index" : "testindex7",
                    "_type" : "_doc",
                    "_id" : "OvU4OG0BCNyxVsPT3Xtn",
                    "_score" : 1.0,
                    "_source" : {
                      "first_name" : "a",
                      "last_name" : "b",
                      "company_domain" : "google",
                      "provider_a_id" : "100",
                      "provider_b_id" : "1"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "_index" : "testindex7",
                    "_type" : "_doc",
                    "_id" : "O_U5OG0BCNyxVsPTAHsD",
                    "_score" : 1.0,
                    "_source" : {
                      "first_name" : "c",
                      "last_name" : "d",
                      "company_domain" : "google",
                      "provider_a_id" : "101",
                      "provider_b_id" : "2"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: the above query still should work for provider_a_id for array values [1, 2, 3, ....1000]. try it out

Comment: Thanks @JBone for the comment, I have updated query to include multiple ids

Comment: @jaspreetchahal, you are a truly beloved man, captain. I have around 300M documents and this query takes 10secs for minor a simple example. Are they way to improve this query performance? I don't need score calculation if it helps. EDIT: I switched the aggregation by filtering by id at the beginning at this now take 1 second.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza  this query should be running in milliseconds. What is index document count, and ram size?

Comment: @jaspreetchahal: I have   `"hits" : {  "total" : 128308801,`. However I still have to investigate more in deep now that you helped me out. I'll create a separate question if needed. Once again, thanks for the help.

Comment: If you don’t need documents just the aggregation you can give size as zero( as in my answer). If documents are required it is better to move filter in query as in @anji v ‘s answer

Answer (score 1):

Query with aggs

```
"query":{
        "term":{
          "provider_a_id":"1234"        
        }
    },
"aggs": {
    "COMPANIES": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "company_domain.keyword",
        "order": { "_key": "asc" }, 
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "EMPLOYEES": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is only matching one specific id... how can I do to check multiples IDs like `provider_a_id` is in `[1,2,3,4,5,6.......1000]`

Comment: Using "terms":{"provider_a_id":[1,2,3]}